# Cannot Recrop Thumbnail of Image in Gallery in WordPress

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails

I have uploaded pictures to be included in a gallery in a post in a WordPress blog. I'm using the template 'my base 0.5'

Basically, the thumbnail that's automatically generated when I upload the picture is drawn from the dead center of the picture (a square). Some of the pictures are of people so the head gets cut off. If you click on the picture's thumbnail, the full picture is displayed in its own page.

So then I went into the Media Library and clicked 'Edit Image' under the displayed thumbnail to try to change the thumbnail. I reselect a different area of the picture, I clicked on "Thumbnail" under the header "Apply sizes to:" but it will not allow me to click the Save button. The button basically doesn't become highlighted as an option to click.

Is this a common problem? I've searched around a little bit but didn't seem to find anything specific to the problem I'm having. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Before you hitting save button you must click the crop button from the buttons above the image (first button) after you selected the area

Comment: Why did I get the -1? I thought my question was pretty thorough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I'm explaining the steps to update the thumbnail:

1. Goto media gallery and click the `Edit Image` button.
2. Under Thumbnail settings click `Thumbnail`.
3. Make sure to select “1:1” Aspect ratio.
4. Hold down your shift key and make the selection. Because you made
   the aspect ratio 1:1 the selection will be a square.
5. You’ve now got to click the “crop” tool button. This will finalize
   the crop. [image: Crop tool]
6. You can now hit “Save”.
7. Click “Update Media”. You’re Thumbnail view should now be updated!

Cheers!!!